# How to make some ListView items 'greyed-out' and unselectable?

Tags: c#, windows-store-apps, winrt-xaml, windows-8.1-universal

Some items in the ListView control will be selectable and have normal text.
Some items however, although included in the ListView as items, will be unselectable/unclickable and 'greyed-out'.

In Windows-Store-Apps we have the ability to select Single/Multiple/None items in a ListView. But how can make certain items at certain indexes unselectable/unclickable and 'greyed-out', in code mainly?

I managed to access the Item of the ListView at a certain index:

```
myListView.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromIndex(i)
```

But I couldn't find any option to customize its selected event handler.
Any idea how to achieve that?

Comment: Are you trying this with Single Selection mode or multiple selection mode?

Comment: Single selection mode

Comment: check my answer it may resolve your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found a solution:

I have override the `ListView` control and create a StripedListView. Then by overriding the `PrepareContainerForItemOverride`, which is responsible for the setting up the `ListViewItem` control after it’s be created, you could modify the background color and set the `ItemListView.isEnabled` option to false:

```
public class StripedListView : ListView
    {          
        protected override void PrepareContainerForItemOverride(DependencyObject element, object item)
        {
            base.PrepareContainerForItemOverride(element, item);
            var listViewItem = element as ListViewItem;
            if (listViewItem != null)
            {
                var index = IndexFromContainer(element);

                if (Words.arrayW[index].Length > 0)
                {
                    listViewItem.Foreground = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Black);

                }
                else
                {
                    listViewItem.Foreground = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Gray); 
                    listViewItem.IsEnabled = false;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

In Xaml:

```
<controls:StripedListView x:Name="letterListView" ItemsSource="{Binding}">   
      <controls:StripedListView.ItemTemplate>  
         <DataTemplate>                           
                etc...              
         </DataTemplate>
      </controls:StripedListView.ItemTemplate>
</controls:StripedListView>
```

Answer (score 1):

In Single selection mode.
First Add a boolean property to class of binding type which defines which items are clickable like this

```
  class TestClass
  {
    Boolean IsClickAllowed{get;set;}
    string name{get;set;}
  }
```

then create a source list of TestClass type and set it as itemssource of Listview like this

```
var TempList=new List<>()
                    {
                        new TextClass(){IsClickAllowed=false,name="First Item"},
                        new TextClass(){IsClickAllowed=true,name="Second Item"},
                        new TextClass(){IsClickAllowed=false,name="Third Item"},
                    };
                    MyList.ItemsSource=TempList;
```

and for greying out Set Different DataTemplate for nonClickable items implementing *DataTemplateSelector* and finally for click handle in ItemClick event. You need to set IsItemClickEnabled as true.

```
private void MyList_ItemClick(object sender, ItemClickEventArgs e)
        {
            var item = e.ClickedItem as TestClass;
            if (item != null){
if(item.IsClickAllowed){
//Do Stuff here
}else
{
//Do Nothing
}
        }}
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks for your answer @Rohit! I have found an optimal one using `isEnabled`